# In an AppSync @auth rule, how do I set an ownerField to a property in an array?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

Imagine I have the following AppSync GraphQL schema with a `User` type, and a `Post` type with an `editors` field set to an array of `User`s:

```
type User
  @model 
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner }
  ])
{
  id: ID!
  owner: String!
  username: String!
}

type Post
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner },
    # Can I do this?
    # { allow: owner, ownerField: "editors.owner", operations: [update] }
  ])
{
  id: ID!
  owner: String!
  title: String!
  content: String
  editors: [User]
}
```

How do I create an `@auth` rule to give update permissions to the `User`s in the `editors` array?

Comment: @Hoarce Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ataravati, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @HackRx What I ended up doing was creating a lambda resolver with `@function`.

Comment: @ataravati lambda resolver on queries/mutation right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the amazon Cognito user pool you should set the editor type inside Post to be an array of String and set the values to the Cognito ids of the users that you want to have access. This is explained [in the amplify cli documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#owner-authorization).

To have the editors to be of type User I suggest you to create another paramether named differently (for example editorUsers) and connect it to the User model as described [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#has-many)

Your schema should look like this:

```
type User
@model
@key(name: "byUser", fields: ["username"]) 
@auth(rules: [
 { allow: owner }
])
{
  id: ID!
  owner: String!
  username: String!
}

type Post
@model
@auth(rules: [
  { allow: owner },
  { allow: owner, ownerField: "editors", operations: [update] }
])
{
  id: ID!
  owner: String!
  title: String!
  content: String
  editors: [String]
  editorsUsers: [User] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}
```